# Can i keep a track of the time taken for report generation using either Macros or UFT or iMacros?

Tags: web-applications, macros, report, imacros, hp-uft

I have to test the time taken for each report generation in a web application, before and after deployment. 10 different reports are there and with different filter criteria.
I want to know if there is a way to capture the exact time taken in report generation using MACROS or UFT or iMacros.

Comment: You need to provide more details, like what kind of reports you are talking about and how your creating these results and so on...

Comment: Certainly, you can use [stopwatches](http://wiki.imacros.net/STOPWATCH) in 'iMacros'. [Here](http://wiki.imacros.net/Demo-Stopwatch) is a demo example too.

Answer (score 0):

The provided answer by Shugar is correct.
By using

> STOPWATCH ID=id

you can stop the time between two ID's with same description.
For example:

```
STOPWATCH ID=Time123
WAIT SECONDS =58
STOPWATCH ID=Time123
```

Then you'll find on your pc at: C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\iMacros\Downloads a file called performance with your script name. This file then shows you the time between the two STOPWATCHES and that would be 58 in this case.